# getting the value of ajax and incrementing/concatting it to other value codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

i have a problem in my ajax. Here is my serious problem. When i go to my view, sometimes it displays 1-0 and thats what i want, but sometimes it only displays -0. What i did is , i am getting an ID from the database and put it in a label, after i put it in a label, i get it again and concat with other ID that is came from my database again. Here is my code:

my ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  get_clinicID();
});

function getcheckupID() {

var init = 0;
var value = $('#clinicID').html();

  $.ajax ({
    url: siteurl+"myclinic/getcheckID",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.length>0) {
          $('#checkID').text(value+"-"+data[0]['clinic_id']+1);
          $("#checkID").css('visibility','visible');
        }
        else {
          $('#checkID').text(value+"-"+init);
          $("#checkID").css('visibility','visible');

        }
    }
  }) 
}

function get_clinicID() {
      $("#clinicID").empty();
      $.ajax({
            url: siteurl+"myclinic/get_clinicID",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data) {
                $('#clinicID').text(data[0]['clinic_id']);
            }
      });
    }
```

My view:

```
<div class="col-title">
          <h4> Your Clinic ID: &nbsp;<label id="clinicID"></label></h4>
            <br>
          <h5 id="checkupID">Check-up ID: &nbsp;<label id="checkID"></label> </h5>
          </div><!-- col-title -->
```

The Problem: If i go refresh/reload the page the output of my concat from the code below becomes -0, the actual output that i want is 1-0, sometimes it outputs 1-0, but sometimes its not. Is it delayed from ajax? or something wrong in my code below :

```
success: function(data) {
            if(data.length>0) {
              $('#checkID').text(value+"-"+data[0]['clinic_id']+1);
              $("#checkID").css('visibility','visible');
            }
            else {
              $('#checkID').text(value+"-"+init);
              $("#checkID").css('visibility','visible');

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this near :

```
text(value.toString()+"-"+init);
```

Comment: how sir ? 
$('#checkID').text(value.toString+"-"+init); ? it outputs "undefined-0"

Comment: it will prevent subtraction